# Why does _GET in PHP wrongly decodes slash?

Tags: php, get, escaping

Today I run into some oddity with PHP, which I fail find a proper explanation for in the documentation. Consider the following code:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['t']. PHP_EOL;
?>
```

The code is simple - it takes a single t parameter on the url and outputs it back. So if you call it with test.php?t=%5Ca (%5c is a '\'), I expected to see:

```
\a
```

However, this is what I got:

```
$ curl http://localhost/~boaz/test.php?t=%5Ca
\\a
```

Notice the double slash. Can anyone explains what's going on and give recipe for retrieving the strings as it was supplied on the URL?

Thanks,
Boaz

PS. I'm using PHP 5.2.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens, because you have the "magic quotes" switch in php.ini switched on. From the manual:

> When on, all ' (single-quote), "
>   (double quote), \ (backslash) and NULL
>   characters are escaped with a
>   backslash automatically. This is
>   identical to what addslashes() does.

Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

To make your script aware of any value of the "magic_quotes_gpc" setting in php.ini, you can write your script like this:

```
$d = $_GET["d"];
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $d = stripslashes($d);
echo $d; //but now you are kind of vulnerable to SQL injections
         //if you don't properly escape this value in SQL queries.
```

Comment: Which can be cured by using stripslashes()

Comment: you are vulnerable to SQL injection if you are depending on magic quotes to protect you.  You should always use parameterized queries.  No excuses.

Comment: Magic_quotes is going to be removed in PHP 6 by the way, so it's wise not to rely on it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix this using the strip_slashes() function. You should avoid magic quotes; they've been deprecated for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

open .htaccess file and put something like this

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
```