# How do I remove backslashes from JSON.stringify in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does php insert backslash while replacing double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017420/why-does-php-insert-backslash-while-replacing-double-quotes)

How can you remove the backslashes from a `JSON.stringify()` after it is sent with AJAX?

The JSON before I send it does not have the backslashes, and afterwards it does. Are the backslashes always added by PHP when it encounters double quotes in a string?

Post-ajax output of `JSON.stringify()`:

```
[
   {
      \"firstname\":\"John\",
      \"lastname\":\"Doe\"
   },
   {
       \"firstname\":\"Jane\",
       \"lastname\":\"Smith\"
   }
]
```

Comment: Output to where? I have a feeling that it's working correctly, but you're viewing it in an interface that has to escape the quotes.

Comment: what's your input, look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/XAnJj/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try php [stripslashes](http://php.net/strip_slashes) function to remove them

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) feature.

Comment: Does that open up security holes?

Comment: @DonnyP disabling magic quotes will cause severe security problems if your code relies on that setting, so don't rely on it.

Comment: This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. @DonnyP