# PHP $_GET NOT WORKING (BackSlashes Duplicated)

Tags: get, backslash

I am having the exact same issue as shown here: [Why does _GET in PHP wrongly decodes slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448332/why-does-get-in-php-wrongly-decodes-slash)

An HTML form passes the parameters, so there is no need for urlencode(). If it passes a single backslash ("%5c") on the URL, then "$_GET[name]" will return 2 slashes for every one passed!

I am on **PHP 7.4**, and I understand that magic slashes have been removed in that, so the solution for the old issue doesn't apply to me.  In any case, I tried to turn off "magic_quotes_gpc" in PHP (set_ini) as well as ".htaccess".

Comment: "I am on PHP 5.4" — **Danger!** That version of PHP has been unsupported for almost 8 years. It hasn't had any security updates in that time. Upgrade to a supported version of PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I meant PHP 7.4

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have worked out the answer, while PHP has removed magic quotes from "**$_GET**", "**$_POST**", "**$_COOKIE**", and "**$_SERVER**", WordPress decided to fu&k everyone up by adding similar magic quotes without the ability to turn it off!

That means you can't safely use the contents as is but must process it via "**[wp_unslash()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unslash/)**":

```
Unf = wp_unslash( _GET['parm'] );
```